# Integral formula doesn't hold here?

Tags: calculus, integration, physics, indefinite-integrals

The following formula (from my integration sheets provided from college):
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}=\ln ({x+\sqrt{a^2+x^2}})+C$$
appears that it doesn't hold for this classic physics problem:
A particle is moving along a trajectory with acceleration $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4+t^2}}$ $\frac{m}{s^2}$. Find the velocity of the particle at $t=1$ second, if its initial velocity (at $t=0$) is $v=5\:\frac{m}{s}$.
According to the formula the result should simply be $$\ln\:({1+\sqrt{4+1}})+5\approx6.17\:\frac{m}{s}$$
The result we obtained should be incorrect.
If we dig deeper into the actual integral and solve it using the hyperbolic substitution $(x=u\sinh t)$, and identity $\cosh^2 t-\sinh^2 t=1$ we obtain the following $$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}=\ln \left( \frac{x}{a}+\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{a^2}} \right)+C$$
And if we now calculate the solution using this formula, the solution is correct: $$v\approx5.48\:\frac{m}{s}.$$
I know that we can factor out $\frac{1}{a}$ and get
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}=\ln \left(\frac{1}{a} \left( x+\sqrt{a^2+x^2} \right)\right)+C.$$
and then rewrite this as a sum of two natural logarithms from which one is a constant and get the exact equation that we started with in the first place, but exactly this step produces the error into this physics problem.

*Now, the question is, since the formula **must** hold for every integration (and thus this physics problem) isn't the provided formula literally wrong? Since it must hold in every situation, factoring out $\frac{1}{a}$ and ultimately rewriting it as the sum of two logarithms and joining it with a constant would produce an error in some tasks so, logically, this step, although mathematically correct, for a formula can't be done?

Comment: I'd find it a bit easier to work with $\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}=\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}\right)+C,$ myself.

Comment: Your calculation of $+C$ for the first case was entirely incorrect. It is not $5$ because $\log(0 + \sqrt{4+0}) = \log(2) \neq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the integral result to the velocity

$$v(t) = \int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{4+t^2}}=\ln ({t+\sqrt{4+t^2}})+C$$

Substitute the initial condition $v(0) = 5$ to obtain the constant $C$

$$5 =\ln (2)+C\implies C = 5-\ln(2)$$

Therefore,

$$v(t)=\ln ({t+\sqrt{4+t^2}})-\ln(2)+5$$

Then, evaluate $v(t)$ for $t=1$,

$$v(1)=\ln ({1+\sqrt{4+1}})-\ln(2)+5=5.48 \text{ m}/\text{s}$$

which gives the correct result.